# Python WebDriver - can not use send_keys to uploading file to site. API will active file selection window

Tags: python, selenium

Test scenario：
1. Launch to site (https://app.box.com/files)
2. Login to site, page will redirect to All File page.
3. Click "Upload" button. ---- After click "upload files" and "upload folders" options appeared.
4. Click "upload Files" --- After click it windows file selection window display.

Then Upload files HTML code:

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"            style="position: absolute; top: 34px; left: 0.5px; display: block;" data-type="upload-menu" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-3">
<li class="ui-menu-item" data-type="upload-files-option" role="presentation" style="position: relative;" tabindex="-1">
<a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Upload Files</a>
</li>
```

I use following code try to uploading file.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
sDataFile = "D:\\TestData\\Test.txt"
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='ui-id-2']").send_keys(sDataFile)
```

When I run this code the file cannot be uploaded successfully, webdriver will activate windows file selection dialog, but file cannot been uploaded. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing the below line make sure you are selecting the input component for send_keys.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

i.e. in html you will have a component like below. Make sure using xpath you select below element and then apply send_keys

```
<input type="file" />
```

Comment: if I have data-type = 'upload-files-option' in html. Can I use send_keys to uploading a file?